# The determinant of the matrix is very big, and solving becomes very difficult

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I have a matrix of R1 of dimension 14 cross 14. I am trying to take the determinant, which happened to be the function of x and trying to find the roots of the determinant equation. But the det equation is too big and it is taking too much time to solve for roots. How to over come this?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

Y1 = 2*10^11;
L1 = 4;
aa1 = 0.1;
bb1 = 0.1;
a1 = aa1*bb1;
den1 = 7850;
Iyy1 = (aa1*bb1^3)/12;


rle1 = 0.25;
rar1 = 1;
rym1 = 1;
rde1 = 1;

rle2 = 0.25;
rar2 = 1;
rym2 = 1;
rde2 = 1;

L2 = rle1*L1;
a2 = rar1*a1;
Y2 = rym1*Y1;
den2 = rde1*den1;

L3 = rle2*L1;
a3 = rar2*a1;
Y3 = rym2*Y1;
den3 = rde2*den1;

z[1] = L1/3;
z[2] = 3.2;

n = 2; 

W[1] = c[1]*Sin[b*x1] + c[2]*Cos[b*x1] + c[3]*Sinh[b*x1] + 
   c[4]*Cosh[b*x1];
W[2] = c[5]*Sin[b*(x1 - z[1])] + c[6]*Cos[b*(x1 - z[1])] + 
   c[7]*Sinh[b*(x1 - z[1])] + c[8]*Cosh[b*(x1 - z[1])];
W[3] = c[9]*Sin[b*(x1 - z[2])] + c[10]*Cos[b*(x1 - z[2])] + 
   c[11]*Sinh[b*(x1 - z[2])] + c[12]*Cosh[b*(x1 - z[2])];
w = Piecewise[{{W[1], x1 <= z[1]}, {W[2], z[1] <= x1 <= z[2]}, {W[3], 
     x1 >= z[2]}}];


boundary[i_, j_] := 
 Module[ {bc}, 
  bc1 = {W[i] /. {x1 -> 0}, (D[W[i], {x1, 2}]) /. {x1 -> 0}, 
    W[j] /. {x1 -> L1}, ((D[W[j], {x1, 2}]) /. {x1 -> L1})}; bc = bc1]

countinuity[i_, j_] := 
 Module[{eq}, 
  eq1 = {((W[i] /. x1 -> z[i]) - (W[j] /. 
        x1 -> z[i])), (((D[W[i], {x1}]) /. 
        x1 -> z[i]) - ((D[W[j], {x1}]) /. 
        x1 -> z[i])), (((D[W[i], {x1, 2}]) /. 
        x1 -> z[i]) - ((D[W[j], {x1, 2}]) /. 
        x1 -> z[i])), (((D[W[i], {x1, 3}]) /. 
         x1 -> z[i]) - ((D[W[j], {x1, 3}]) /. x1 -> z[i])) + (K[i]*
        W[i] /. x1 -> z[i])}; eq = eq1 ]

e1 = boundary[1, 3];
e2 = countinuity[1, 2];
e3 = countinuity[2, 3];
comb = Tuples[{0, 1*^12}, 3];
eq = Flatten[{e1, e2, e3}];
var = Table[c[i], {i, 1, Length[eq]}];
R = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eq, var][[2]];
R = R /. {K[1] -> K1, K[2] -> K2};
P = b^10 (K1 K2 (8. Cos[0.533333 b] - 8. Cos[2.13333 b]) Cosh[
       0.533333 b] - 8. K1 K2 Cos[0.533333 b] Cosh[2.13333 b] + 
     8. K1 K2 Cos[2.13333 b] Cosh[2.13333 b] - 
     4. K1 K2 Cos[1.33333 b] Cosh[2.4 b] + 
     4. K1 K2 Cos[4. b] Cosh[2.4 b] + 
     4. K1 K2 Cos[1.33333 b] Cosh[4. b] + 
     4. K1 K2 Cos[2.4 b] Cosh[4. b] - 8. K1 K2 Cos[4. b] Cosh[4. b] - 
     2. K1 K2 Cosh[0.266667 b] Sin[4. b] + 
     2. K1 K2 Cosh[0.266667 b] Sin[4. b] + 
     16. b^3 K2 Cosh[2.4 b] Sin[4. b] - 
     16. b^3 K1 Cosh[4. b] Sin[4. b] - 
     16. b^3 K2 Cosh[4. b] Sin[4. b] + 
     K1 Cosh[1.33333 b] (-4. K2 Cos[2.4 b] + 4. K2 Cos[4. b] + 
        16. b^3 Sin[4. b]) + 2. K1 K2 Sin[4. b] Sinh[0.266667 b] + 
     2. K1 K2 Sin[4. b] Sinh[0.266667 b] + 
     4. K1 K2 Sin[4. b] Sinh[1.33333 b] + 
     4. K1 K2 Sin[4. b] Sinh[
       2.4 b] + ((0. - 2. I) K1 K2 Cos[
          0.266667 b] + (0. + 2. I) K1 K2 Cos[0.266667 b] + 
        16. b^3 K1 Cos[1.33333 b] + 16. b^3 K2 Cos[2.4 b] - 
        16. b^3 K1 Cos[4. b] - 16. b^3 K2 Cos[4. b] - 
        2. K1 K2 Sin[0.266667 b] - 2. K1 K2 Sin[0.266667 b] - 
        4. K1 K2 Sin[1.33333 b] - 4. K1 K2 Sin[2.4 b] - 
        64. b^6 Sin[4. b]) Sinh[4. b]);
f[k1_, k2_, beta_] := 
  Module[{m}, K1 = k1; K2 = k2; r = beta; s1 = P; 
   s2 = NSolve[s1 == 0 && 0 < b < 30]; s3 = N[b /. s2]; 
   s4 = s3[[r]]; {uu, ww, vv} = 
    SingularValueDecomposition[R /. b -> s4]; 
   NN = Last[Transpose[vv]];   sub1 = Flatten[{var, b}]; 
   sub2 = Flatten[{NN, s4}];    
   m = w /. Table[sub1[[i]] -> sub2[[i]], {i, 1, Length[sub1]}]; 
   Return[m]];
comb = Tuples[{0, 1*^12}, 2];
g[i_, r_] := 
 Module[{s5}, spring = comb[[i]]; n1 = spring[[1]]; 
  n2 = spring[[2]];  n3 = r; s5 = f[n1, n2, n3]]
beammodes1 = Table[g[i, 1], {i, 1, 2^n}];
beammodes2 = Table[g[i, 2], {i, 1, 2^n}];
beammodes = Flatten[{beammodes1, beammodes2}];
Table[Plot[beammodes[[i]], {x1, 0, L1}, PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, 
  Length[beammodes]}]

W = Expand[
   Total[Table[c[i]*beammodes[[i]], {i, 1, Length[beammodes]}]]];
Wxx = Expand[D[W, {x1, 2}]];
in1 = Expand[(Wxx)^2];
in2 = Expand[(W)^2];
var1 = Table[c[i], {i, 1, Length[beammodes]}];

rules1 = CoefficientRules[in1, var1];
rules1[[All, 2]] = NIntegrate[rules1[[All, 2]], {x1, 0, L1}];
v1 = 0.5*Iyy1*Y1*Chop[(FromCoefficientRules[rules1, var1])]


rules2 = CoefficientRules[in2, var1];
rules2[[All, 2]] = NIntegrate[rules2[[All, 2]], {x1, 0, L1}];
t1 = 0.5*den1*a1*x^2*Chop[(FromCoefficientRules[rules2, var1])]


fixedfree1 = Table[Sin[(2*i - 1)/(2*L2)*\[Pi]*x2], {i, 1, 1}];
fixedfixed1 = Table[Sin[(i*\[Pi]*x2)/L2], {i, 1, 1}];
barmodes1 = Flatten[{fixedfree1, fixedfixed1}];
Table[Plot[barmodes1[[i]], {x2, 0, L2}], {i, 1, Length[barmodes1]}]
U1 = Expand[
   Total[Table[d[i]*barmodes1[[i]], {i, 1, Length[barmodes1]}]]];
U1x = Expand[D[U1, {x2, 1}]];
in3 = Expand[(U1x)^2];
in4 = Expand[(U1)^2];
var2 = Table[d[i], {i, 1, Length[barmodes1]}];
v2 = (0.5*Y2*a2)*Chop[(Integrate[in3, {x2, 0, L2}])]
t2 = (0.5*den2*a2*x^2)*Chop[(Integrate[in4, {x2, 0, L2}])]


fixedfree2 = Table[Sin[(2*i - 1)/(2*L3)*\[Pi]*x3], {i, 1, 1}];
fixedfixed2 = Table[Sin[(i*\[Pi]*x3)/L3], {i, 1, 1}];
barmodes2 = Flatten[{fixedfree2, fixedfixed2}];
Table[Plot[barmodes2[[i]], {x3, 0, L3}], {i, 1, Length[barmodes2]}];
U2 = Expand[
   Total[Table[b[i]*barmodes2[[i]], {i, 1, Length[barmodes2]}]]];
U2x = Expand[D[U2, {x3, 1}]];
in5 = Expand[(U2x)^2];
in6 = Expand[(U2)^2];
var3 = Table[b[i], {i, 1, Length[barmodes2]}];
v3 = (0.5*Y3*a3)*Chop[(Expand[(Integrate[in5, {x3, 0, L3}])])]
t3 = (0.5*den3*a3*x^2)*Chop[(Expand[(Integrate[in6, {x3, 0, L3}])])]

(*Defining Lagrangian *)
T = t1 + t2 + t3;
V = v1 + v2 + v3;
Lg = (T - V) + lam1*((W /. x1 -> z[1]) - (U1 /. x2 -> L2)) + 
   lam2*((W /. x1 -> z[2]) - (U2 /. x3 -> L3));
variables = Flatten[{var1, var2, var3, lam1, lam2}]
equations = 
  Table[D[Lg, {variables[[i]], 1}], {i, 1, Length[variables]}];
R1 = Normal@CoefficientArrays[equations, variables][[2]]
R1 = Rationalize[R1];
MatrixForm[R1]
MatrixRank[R1]
P = Det[R1];
Dimensions[R1]




q1 = NSolve[P == 0 && 0 < x < 10000]
q2 = x /. s1
```

Comment: The determinant is an aid to abstract mathematical reasoning. Actually calculating it is rarely a good way to approach a problem. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am doing Eigen value analysis

Comment: Ok I will put my entire code. only last few line I am facing difficulty

Comment: You are likely to have severe numerical problems: you have terms with 10^10 and others of size 10^-16 in the same equation.

Comment: how to resolve this, I looked at the contributions of v1, v2,v3, t1,t2, and t3. I Think the formation of lagrangian include these terms which result in these two extreme numerical values I guess

Comment: To solve for eigenvalues, you probably should use the `Eigenvalues` function: it has the capability to use specialized methods for this kind of problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, eigenvalue function suits only for a matrix containing numerics. I have an unknown variable x in  my final matrix

Comment: Works fine for symbolic matrices for me. Try `Eigenvalues[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]`.

Comment: For symbolic methods, it's good to avoid inexact numbers. `0.5` may cause trouble, where `1/2` doesn't.

Comment: Actually I am solving a matrix A which is a function of x i.e A(x), I am interested in solving for A(x)=0, Which forces me to take determinant of A(x), and find the roots of the determinant function  which leads  to the eigenvalue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88749/discussion-between-acoustics-and-john-doty).